# Why access to the database is faster depending on order of calls to database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, .net-core

I create a comparasion program for dapper, ado.net and EFCore. My problem is that if I call first dapper it has around 7 seconds and third EFCore has around 6 seconds, but if I call EFCore first it has around 7 seconds and third dapper 5 seconds.
Here is my code for calling one of each access.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i ++)
        {
            string dapperSync = dapperService.SelectDapperSync();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            string adoSync = adoService.SelectAdoSync();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            string efCoreSync = eFCoreService.SelectEFCoreSync();
        }
```

I'd like to know why that happen? Is any cache, metadata in database or program? I tried close connection manually instead of use only "using", but result was same. I use MSSQL and .NET Core 2.1. Is there any way how repair that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ado.Net (on which dapper and entity framework are based) implements a [connection pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling) - meaning that the first time you create a connection to the database there's the overhead of creating the actual underlying connection - and when you close or dispose the instance of `SqlConnection`, the underlying connection still remains available in the connection pool for a while, so the second and third time does not have that overhead - the new instance of SqlConnection simply use the already opened connection from the connection pool.

> The connection pooler removes a connection from the pool after it has been idle for approximately 4-8 minutes, or if the pooler detects that the connection with the server has been severed. Note that a severed connection can be detected only after attempting to communicate with the server.

To eliminate this effect, you can open a connection and close it immediately before running the loops - this connection will have the overhead of establishing the first connection and keep an available connection in the pool so your tests would be more accurate.